# Change Color after trigger or cross a cube in Unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, colors, triggers

I am new in Unity and I have a question, I have a sphere(player) and 4 cubes, two is red and two is blue (which they are aligned with each other), and there is one black cube in the end, what I want is that after crossing that black cube is two change the color to red or blue, and I want if the sphere(player) is red it could walk in the red cube but when it touches the blue cube it stops, and the same thing with the red, so anyone can help??!!, I really need help because this is the last part of my project.....

Regards.
Osama

Answer (score 0):

- You need to create an empty game object with a 3D Collider on it
- check the checkbox of the collider so the collider becomes a trigger
- write a script with one or more of these functions depending on the behavior you want

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html

Then you need a reference to your four other cubes and change their color.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html

EDIT:
Generally we are here to help you and not to do the work for you. I **highly** suggest you follow some tutorials on how to script in unity.

If you want to "walk through" gameobjects you will need to enable and disable the collider or the whole object based on trigger collision.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/enabling-and-disabling-components#

Comment: I did an Object with 3D collider, and I checked the check box, but the problem is that I am not knowing how to write the script, so please can you help me with it, here is the name of the objects:

Comment: The Blue cube is (BLUE), The Red cube is (RED) and The Black cube is (Ground).

Comment: Sorry. I did not fully understand what you wanted to achive. If it was just for the color change I would have written you a script but you also need to enable and disable colliders if you want to "walk through the cubes". If you have some code I will help you but without anything it's gonna be hard.

Comment: I have a movement script and a collision script, and yes I want to enable and disable colliders if the color does not match, I could give u the scripts, thanks